# REST API :Return list attachment file created/ modified date and GUID

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint list and the items within this list have one or more files attached. I need to mirror/ replicate these attachments to a client’s document repository.

To this end, I am trying to determine

1. The attachments created date/ time (when the file was attached to the list item)
2. The attachments last modified date/time
3. The attachments GUID/ ID (I need a primary key to identify the document)

I am somewhat new to the SharePoint API and am struggling a little! I have tried the call below, but it does not contain the information I am looking for. Can anyone suggest a call or endpoint that might return what I’m looking for?

```
http://mysite/_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this would solve the problem of getting an Id/GUID but you could use

```
http://mysite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('ServerRelativeUrl')
```

to get the created date/time and modified date/time of the attachment.  You would have to make this call for each individual attachment though.  For a normal SharePoint file you could append /ListItemAllFields to the end of the url, which would allow you to get the ID, but it appears ListItemAllFields is null for attachments.

Comment: Hi James- this is perfect and does indeed return the files GUID.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I think the GUID is returned in SharePoint Online but isn't returned if you are using SharePoint Server 2013